# Is it possible to engage multiple cores (like gcc -j8) when solving with Pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

The power flow library PyPSA uses Pyomo. I am trying to reduce the cost of each linear optimal power flow simulation.

I read through the Pyomo [docs](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/). Nothing sticks out at me yet. Perhaps it is not possible to split up the processing when solving linear optimisation problems.

Ubuntu 19.04, i5-4210U 1.70 GHz, 8 Gb RAM

Comment: We need more infos on *what*  exactly you want to parralelize. Do you have many independant problems to solve at the same time, or do you have a bigger problem that solves on only one CPU core, that you want to solve separetedly?

Comment: I have a bigger problem that current solves on only one CPU core. I want to know if there is a quick option to tell Pyomo to use more cores. The objective function being solved can be found in [this PyPSA paper - pg 4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09913.pdf). I would not be surprised if splitting up the solving over multiple cores requires splitting up the problem from the start. Just wondering if I can get some free lunch.

Comment: This is generally handled by the solver. Do you know which solver is being used by Pyomo in PyPSA?

Comment: gplk and cbc appear to be the most common

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about processing there are two things to consider. Processing to write the .lp file and processing to solve the problem with an optimization solver.

First, writing the .lp file is to my knowledge not yet parallelized in Pyomo. PyPSA developers created [Linopy](https://github.com/PyPSA/linopy) to parallel the processing to reduce RAM requirements and increase the speed.

Second, parallelizing the solver processing depends on the solver. PyPSA-Eur has an example of integration for that for [Gurobi, and CPLEX](https://github.com/PyPSA/pypsa-eur/blob/a4e5748d12f0f554ebb3ceb6c32e368b1aadd146/config.default.yaml#L227-L243). The [performant open-source solver HiGHS](https://pypsa-meets-africa.github.io/highs.html) can also something like that see [here](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS).